# SQL Server Compare Month-Day portion of date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, concatenation

I'm trying to compare 2 people and see whose birthday falls earlier in the year. I'm trying to hack together a solution where I take the mm-dd from a datetime field using RIGHT(DOB, 5) and concatenating it with '1900' to create a new date field and use that for comparison.

```
 CONVERT(DATE,'1900-' + RIGHT(DOB,5),126) DOB
```

However I'm getting the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Any suggestions for how to fix this?

Comment: do you have any examples of your DOB values?

Comment: Is your DOB column actually a date column?  Based on your example it looks like a string which could well have invalid data for constructing dates.

Comment: Remove the convert and look at the values. There must be something wrong in your data.

Comment: You are using RIGHT(SomeDate, 5) which will NOT return mm-dd. It will return a colon, the minutes and AM/PM. select right(getdate(), 5)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
right(convert (char(10), dob, 120), 5)
```

the 120 format is yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
format(date,'MMdd')
```

Comment: ***IF*** he's on SQL Server **2012** or newer - yes - that's a new 2012 function, though - not available in older versions